# Custom Stripe checkout button not working without duplicate script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe Checkout button in a Rails application (Part 1 below) that works well. I wanted to customize the button style, so I followed the guide [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) and added a custom Javascript and button (Part 2).

When both of these parts are included, the second button (Part 2) works well. When I delete Part 1, the second button doesn't pop up the Checkout dialog - instead, it just submits the form without a stripeToken and stripeEmail, causing an error.

Can someone shed some light on what's happening and how to fix this?

```
<!-- Part 1 -->
<div class="hidden">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
              class="stripe-button"
              data-label="Subscribe"
              data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
              data-name="<%= @site.title %>"
              data-description="Monthly Subscription"
              data-amount="<%= @site.price %>"
              data-email="<%= current_user.email %>"></script>
</div>
<!-- End Part 1 -->

<!-- Part 2 -->
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="subscription-button">Subscribe Now</button>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      var tokenInput = $("<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />").val(response.id);
      var emailInput = $("<input type=hidden name=stripeEmail />").val(response.email);
      $("form").append(tokenInput).append(emailInput).submit();
    }
  });

  $('#subscription-button').on('click', function(e) {
    handler.open({
      name: '<%= @site.title %>',
      description: 'Monthly Subscription',
      email: '<%= current_user.email %>'
      amount: <%= @site.price %>
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
<!-- End Part 2 -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a same problem while following a similar [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/variable-amount-checkout).

Including the javascript include tag in the view's layouts file solved the issue.

The view `charges/new.html.erb` is like :

```html
<%=form_tag charges_path do %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
        <p><%=flash[:error] %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>    
  <article>
    <%=label_tag(:amount, 'Donation Amount:') %>
    <%=text_field_tag(:amount) %>
  </article>
  <article>
    <%=hidden_field_tag(:stripeToken) %>
  </article>
  <button id='donateButton'>Donate</button>
<% end %>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_iasdfkjasnflkajshdfa',
    image: '/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token) {
      // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
      // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
    }
  });
  
  $('#donateButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
```

every time our custom button was pressed, the `checkout.js` script failed to load and the further code started executing.

To solve the problem, just include

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout/", "application" %>
```

in your supporting layout file(i.e., `layouts/charges.html.erb` in this case) inside the `<head>` tag.